# Scale bone in pose mode without affecting child bone?

Tags: armature, bones

When I scale a bone in pose mode it will also affect the size of a bone connected to it. How can do it so that the connected bone keeps the same size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uncheck inherit scale in the bone properties
[image]